# page peal z-index issue?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter, z-index

i'm trying to use page peal to hide my current tweets until it's hover'd over // for some reason, when the page first loads (( i'm using chrome )) the text displays until it's hover'd over. not really sure why..

[here it is](http://designr.info) // any ideas ??

Comment: could you please tell us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set overflow:hidden to #pageflip .msg_block